# TensorFlow BasicLSTMCell vs LSTMFusedBlockCell

Tags: python, tensorflow, lstm, recurrent-neural-network

I am new in TensorFlow. I have managed to build a graph that uses LSTMs to train a basic model using a `BaiscLSTMCell`, based on the TensorFlow tutorial.

But I need to make it faster. I have seen a comparison [here](http://returnn.readthedocs.io/en/latest/tf_lstm_benchmark.html) and, since I do not have an Nvidia GPU, the `LSTMBlockFusedCell` seems to be the best option. I had a look at the [documentation](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/contrib/rnn/LSTMBlockFusedCell) and I noticed that the signatures for the `__init__()` and `__call__()` functions are different. Specifically, I am worried about the `cell_clip` parameter in `__init()__` and the `sequence_length` in call. What is more, the `inputs` tensor is of shape `[time_len, batch_size, input_size]`; isn't that different from that of the basic cell (`[batch_size, time_len, input_size]`)? I do not want to use peepholes, so I will leave that to `False` (default).

Could someone explain if there are any other differences (apart from an improvement in the performance) between the `BasicLSTMCell` and the `LSTMBlockFusedCell` and how to properly set the parameters mentioned above to achieve the same result as the original?

Answer (score 0):

The documentation for `LSTMBlockCell` says it should be drop-in compatible with `LSTMCell`, so the same arguments should have the same meaning.

Whether the input tensor is batch-first or time-first is unrelated to the cell and related instead to the dynamic_rnn / static_rnn you're using.